# Googlemaps, I don't find setUserCredentials

Tags: java, google-maps, maven

I have a java project with maven dependency management. Using the Googlemaps dependency, I am unable to find setUserCredentials.

```
MapsService myService = new MapsService(
myService.setUserCredentials("root@gmail.com", "paword");
```

This is my maven dependency in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-maps</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the Java code:

```
package com.google.gdata.client.sample.maps;

import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.maps.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.maps.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetMapsFeed {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Name your service
    MapsService myService = new MapsService("applicationName");
    try {
      // Replace these credentials with your own
      myService.setUserCredentials("username","password");
    } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
    }
    try {
      printUserMaps(myService);
    } catch(ServiceException e) {
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }
  }
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srp2Q.jpg)

Comment: Is MapsService recognized?  I see the method in the API, sound like might be a issue with your Maven setup.

Comment: Mapsservices is recognized,  I can only bring getters not setters.

Comment: I'd say you've got a bigger problem -- the Maps Data API has been deprecated and is no longer available: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html

Comment: Same problem here on PicasawebService. I can't find setUserCredentials. Any fix?

Answer (score 1):

I fight a lot but found the problems. I need add dependency of the core 1.0 and google java-1.40.3 map.2.0.jar. Thanks for all .

Comment: I don't understand. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the version to 1.0 or any other previous version to ensure there is nothing wrong with dependency you've downloaded.

2) Check your local package, `package com.google.gdata.client.sample.maps;` again to ensure you don't have any other version of MapsService

3) Also type Ctrl+T in Eclipse, and see which jar holds this file in your system?

Hope this helps.